# selectedIndex in List after Alert

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a list with an ArrayCollection dataProvider. In my program, there is a button the user can click to perform a function for the selectedIndex of the List, but an Alert is shown first asking them if they are sure they want to perform the action.  After the user answers the Alert, the action is performed on the selectedIndex of the list.

My problem is that selectedIndex = -1 after the Alert window CloseEvent, even though it is clearly selected.  I got around this by performing validateNow() on the list in the code for the Alert CloseEvent.

**My question:** Why do I have to do this and am I doing something wrong? Or is this normal/best practice?  Also, is there a better/best practice to check a List to see if something is selected besides using try-catch.  I don't want the end user to see the generated error if nothing is selected.

Code:

```
//Note: "fl" is a class with "friendsList" bindable ArrayCollection; for the sake of keeping this short I will not include it

private function _removeFriendClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    try {
        if (this.friendsList.selectedIndex != -1) {
            Alert.show("Are you sure you want to remove "+this.fl.friendsList[this.friendsList.selectedIndex].label+" as a friend?", "Remove Friend", Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, this, this._removeFriendConfirm, null, Alert.CANCEL);
        }
    } catch (e:Error) { }
}

private function _removeFriendConfirm(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    this.friendsList.validateNow();
    trace(this.friendsList.selectedIndex);
}
```

So, with the above code, if you take out the validateNow(), an exception is thrown because it thinks the selectedIndex is -1.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour, but the code you show is insufficient to assess what's going on. You'll have to give us a little more to work with.

Comment: Why don't you want to save the selected index before the Alert window?

Comment: @RIAstar I'm not really sure what else to include?

Comment: @Anton I guess I could, but then I'd have to create another variable...

Comment: What version of Flex are you using? I took the code as provided by @Anton and it works. **You don't need another variable**. I'm using Flex 4.6, and inside the `_removeFriendConfirm()` event handler the `selectedIndex` is never -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;

        [Bindable]private var friendsList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{data:"111", label:"Don"}, {data:"222", label:"John"}]);

        private function onBtnRemove():void
        {
            laFriend.text = "";

            try 
            {
                if (cbFriends.selectedIndex != -1) 
                {
                    Alert.show("Are you sure you want to remove " + cbFriends.selectedItem.label + " as a friend?", "Remove Friend", Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, this, this._removeFriendConfirm, null, Alert.CANCEL);
                }
            } catch (e:Error) { }
        }

        private function _removeFriendConfirm(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            laFriend.text = "Selected friend: " + cbFriends.selectedItem.label;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:VBox>
    <s:ComboBox id="cbFriends" dataProvider="{friendsList}"/>
    <s:Button id="btnRemove" label="Remove" click="onBtnRemove()"/>
    <s:Label id="laFriend" text=""/>
</mx:VBox>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you perform selection just before you call your handler?

If you set selectedIndex, you can't get it back immediately because of the livecycle - value shall be commited before you can read it.

Your validateNow forces that commit. However, it shall happen later without enforcing it manually.